# Json Schema Validation of Array or Objects

Tags: jsonschema

I have a set of options for validation:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "parsePosition Validator",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "option1": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "tpye": "number"
            },
            "minItems": 3
        },
        "option2": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
            "tpye": "number"
            },
            "minItems": 3
        },
        "option3": {
            "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "tpye": "number"
                },
                "minItems": 3
            },
            {
                "x": { "type":"number" },
                "y": { "type":"number" },
                "z": { "type":"number" },
                "required": ["x","y","z"]
            }
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        { "required":["option1"] },
        { "required":["option2"] },
        { "required":["option3"] }
    ]
}
```

Essentially the input of the json can be any of the three options. My issue arises when trying to validate option3. Possible inputs could be:

```
{
    "option3": [1,2,3]
}
```

or

```
{
    "option3": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    }
}
```

However, when I use the array rather than objects, the validator does not throw an issue with an empty array or an array of incorrect size.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something very simple...

You haven't put `type: object` in your second subschema in the `oneOf`. for option 3.

The reason you need this is because JSON Schema is a constraints based language.

Specifying `properties`, doesn't mean the the instance location HAS to be an object; You also need to say "this location should be an object".

An array of any size is valid under your subschema `oneOf[1]`, because `properties` and `required are only applicable to an object.

Comment: Also, `x`, `y` and `z` are specified as if they are keywords; they should be wrapped in a `{"properties":{...}` object.

Comment: See, it's EASY to miss basic things! =]